# Is there a CLI to list or download documents not locally cached in iCloud drive?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, cloud-storage, icloud

I have a symbolic link of `~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs` in my home directory. My iCloud Drive is larger than my Mac's SSD, so I can only have some files downloaded locally at anytime.

In Finder, a directory may have dozens of files with iCloud download icons. Using `ls` in Terminal, this directory appears empty (except for directories).

Is there a command line utility to list files that are saved in iCloud but not locally?